# Responsive image grid that takes full remaining viewport space, horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css, image, grid, responsive-design

I am not well versed in responsive design and I can't seem to find solution for required objective.  Here's a mock-up of the layout I want:

[image]

Now, the goal is to have images, without gap, fit in the image-grid container. This container should take full remaining space, to the utmost right and bottom of a browser viewport, but it does not exceed it, so we don't have any scroll-bars. All images are of *identical dimensions*.

Row-column distribution would depend on viewport size and image dimension to prevent unnecessary distortions. This ratio would change when the viewport size hits specific break-point, but in-between break-points, images would fine tune by proportional scaling.

Break-points are managed with media queries and the site has to be mobile friendly, also. I can't use *'vh'* solution for that matter.

I am primarily looking for lightest implementation, so pure CSS solution would be ideal. I've heard about Masonry JS library and derivative library [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), but I didn't have an opportunity to play with it, yet.

Any help on the subject will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem with your request is that images won't scale (via `max-width: 100%; height: auto`) unless their container width is <= the width of the image.  You *can* use media queries to get around this by saying *if the viewport is X wide, then make the images 25% wide* or whatever, but your news column complicates things since it contains text (unless you want to do this the completely lazy way and do everything in px).

Comment: Thanks for an edit, very nice of you, as well as taking the time to provide an answer. I was going to use media queries either way, since it has to accommodate for different devices. This whole thing is still a bit unclear to me, I guess I'll improvise along the way.

Comment: Also, quick question.. Why can't I up vote your comment?

Comment: @user1344799 Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Filling the viewport vertically is easy with percentage `width` and `media-queries`, the issue here is filling the viewport height.

There's always `height: X%` in CSS, but it only works on elements inside a parent with fixed height and a fixed height isn't very responsive. **However:**

### Introducing viewport units:

`1vh` equals 1% of the viewport height, so `50vh` fills the half the viewport while `100vh` is equal to the full height of the viewport. There's are also the `vw` unit for *viewport width*.

[Browser support for viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh).

### Filling the viewport height:

If your wrapper element has `height: 100vh`, then it'll fill the entire viewport height *and* allow its children to make use of `height: X%`.

For instance, if the parent element has `height: 50vh` and its child element has `height: 50%`, the child element's height will be equal to 25% of the viewport height. [Example of this](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/rALpH).

With your mockup, you'll probably want to use `height: 100vh` on a wrapper element containing the navigation and the main area, then set the main element's `height` to something less than 100% to make room for the navigation element. Then, set the height of the images *(or the containers of the images)* to whatever percent you feel appropriate.

Finally, change the percentage `height` of said images/image containers through `media-queries` set to look for the client's viewport height *(set in pixels)*.

*(Note that it's sometimes difficult for browsers to render content when a percentage ends up with half a pixel, so you may want to use a slightly lower value such as 24.99% rather than 25% to avoid these rounding errors)*

### Another problem emerges:

Doing this, you'll probably find that your images are scewed out of proportion. I don't have a written solution to this, but you should be able to fix this setting the images as `background-image` with [`background-size: cover`](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) to an element and resize those elements instead.

If you need the images as `<img>` elements you'll need to find some other solution.

I hope this provides some insight.

Comment: You indeed provided a lot of insight, I never knew _vh & vw_ units even existed. Also, _caniuse_ is a great website, I'm sure it's going to do me good in near future. Usage for _vh_ units seems very evident and intuitive, but the main problem I'm currently aware of, according to _caniuse_, is no support for android browsers. This is a big deal, since the site has to be mobile friendly. As soon as I get enough rep I'm going to upvote you, but I can't yet accept your answer. I didn't explicitly state in question that site has to adapt for mobile, so it's understandable you thought otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get with pure CSS is with Flexbox, but browser support is limited to those that support wrapping (see:  http://caniuse.com/flexbox, IE10 is the only browser with *partial support* that has wrapping).  Right now that list is limited to IE10, Opera, and Chrome.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/fqoxj

Assuming your markup looks something like this:

```
<header>
  Header
</header>

<nav>
  Nav
</nav>

<main>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" />
    <figcaption>What a cute kitten</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" />
    <figcaption>So adorable!</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" />
    <figcaption>Irresistibly cuddly</figcaption>
  </figure>
</main>
```

The CSS would be like this:

```
body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  body {
    display: flex;
  }
}

header {
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-flex: 1 100%;
  -ms-flex: 1 100%;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

nav {
  background: orange;
  -webkit-flex: 1 15em;
  -ms-flex: 1 15em;
  flex: 1 15em;
}

main {
  -webkit-flex: 3 30em;
  -ms-flex: 3 30em;
  flex: 3 30em;

  /* everything below this line is all that really matters
   * everything above this line is controlling the main layout */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  main {
    display: flex;
  }
}

figure {
  display: inline-block; /* fallback for old browsers */
  /* note that the images are 200px wide, this has to match or Chrome does weird stuff */
  -webkit-flex: 1 200px;
  -ms-flex: 1 200px;
  flex: 1 200px;
}

figure img {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

For a mobile device, once you've scaled to the point where the nav should no longer be on the side, you can safely use media queries to control the sizes of the images:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/l2hw4aon

```
figure {
  display: inline-block;
}

figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 40em) {
  figure {
    width: 30%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 30em) {
  figure {
    width: 45%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 20em) {
  figure {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```